# What is the p parameter in a get_posts() parameter array?

Tags: get-posts, template-tags

I've seen code that looks like this:

`get_posts(array('p' => $thumbnail_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment'));`

What is the definition of the p parameter and is it documented anywhere? I can't find anything about it on the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for get_posts().

Comment: Please use WP_Query instead of get_posts. I'm not entirely educated as to why, but I hear it's faster.

Comment: If you don't know why, then please don't leave an answer ... take some time to read up on the differences between the functions and leave an informed response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'p' is for querying a post, as opposed to 'page_id' for querying a page.

It's documented in the [WP_Query codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)